# How to retain null/nan in one of the groupby columns while performing df.groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
group_cols = ['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3']

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C', 54.34],
                   ['A', 'B', np.nan, 61.34],
                   ['B', 'A', 'C', 514.5],
                   ['B', 'A', 'A', 765.4],
                   ['A', 'B', 'D', 765.4]],
                  columns=(group_cols+['Value']))

Group1  Group 2 Group 3  Value
A        B        C     54.34
A        B       nan    61.34
B        A        C     514.5
B        A        A     765.4
A        B        D     765.4
```

When I do a group by on these 3 columns, the nan row somehow gets deleted/dropped.
Ideally, I would want to have the combination ( A, B and nan in this case) to be retained. So a separate row should have been there in my output. However it gets dropped.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3'],as_index=False).sum()

Group1  Group 2 Group 3  Value
A        B        C     54.34
A        B        D     765.4
B        A        A     765.4
B        A        C     514.5
```

For a workaround, I can fillna with some value and then do a group by so that i get to see the row there, however that is not an ideal solution I feel.

Please can you share how i can retain the nan row ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to `fillna` before `groupby` , since groupby will automatically remove the `NaN`

```
df.fillna('NaN',inplace=True)
df2 = df.groupby(['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3'],as_index=False).sum()
df2
  Group1 Group2 Group3   Value
0      A      B      C   54.34
1      A      B      D  765.40
2      A      B    NaN   61.34
3      B      A      A  765.40
4      B      A      C  514.50
```

From the doc :http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html

***> NA and NaT group handling***

> If there are any NaN or NaT values in the
>   grouping key, these will be automatically excluded. In other words,
>   there will never be an “NA group” or “NaT group”. This was not the
>   case in older versions of pandas, but users were generally discarding
>   the NA group anyway (and supporting it was an implementation
>   headache).

Comment: Yes i mentioned fillna as a workaround, but i dont think it is adequate enough. 
Ideally df.groupby should have a argument/parameter to handle/retain these nulls

Comment: @asimo  ummm, base on the doc , I think the groupby behavior is normal

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Wen-Ben, However it really opens a case of debate, as the new version/author/writer seems to have generalised the handling of  NA and NaT group handling in the grouping key assumign that mostly it gets discarded :(

Comment: @asimo, well NaN != NaN so theres a valid argument for why they should not be grouped together at all.

Comment: @ALollz : I am not asking them to be grouped together. Infact it is the opposite. I am asking them to be retained as is, rather than delete those rows without giving any warning or error message

Answer (score 0):

Know this is an old post but this is what worked for me.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Group1', 'Group2', df['Group3'].astype(str)]).sum().reset_index()

  Group1 Group2 Group3   Value
0      A      B      C   54.34
1      A      B      D  765.40
2      A      B    nan   61.34
3      B      A      A  765.40
4      B      A      C  514.50
```

Convert to string or whatever function that is more accurate while grouping.

Edited: nan gets converted to a string 'nan'